# Puppeteer timeout error when crawling a heavy website even after set the timeout to 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am crawling this website https://startupjobs.asia/job/search?q=&job-list-dpl-page=, the website is heavy and load very slow.

The website has 7 pages and so far I've managed to crawl until the third page. If lucky the 4th page.

I've tried cloning the code to make it open a new browser and made it to the 4th page but the problem still persists when I tried to clone it for the 5th and 6th page.

Below is my code.

```js
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer')
const fs = require("fs")


async function start (){

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: [ '--ignore-certificate-errors' ]
    });
    

    var name     = ["Job Name"];
    var country  = ["Country"];
    var company  = ["Company Name"];
    var type     = ["Job Type"];
    var salary   = ["Salary"];
    var skills   = ["Skills Require"];
    var desc     = ["Job Description"];
    var req      = ["Job Requirements"];
    var resp     = ["Job Responsibility"];
    var industry = ["Industry"];

    for (var j=1; j<3; j++){
        await page.waitForXPath(xpath);
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout( 0 );
        
        await page.goto('https://startupjobs.asia/job/search?q=&job-list-dpl-page='+j, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
            timeout: 0
        });

        for ( var i=1; i < 31; i++){

            await page.waitForXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li["+i+"]/div/div[1]/div/h5/a")
            var b = await page.$x("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li["+i+"]/div/div[1]/div/h5/a")
            await b[0].click();
            
            const elementsToFind = [
                { xpath: "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li["+i+"]/div/div[1]/div/h5/a",  propName: 'job_name' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/h6[2]/a',                    propName: 'country' },      
                { xpath: "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li["+i+"]/div/div[1]/div/p[1]/a",propName: 'company' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/p',         propName: 'job_type' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p',         propName: 'salary' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/p',         propName: 'skills' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div',       propName: 'job_description' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div',       propName: 'job_requirement' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div',       propName: 'job_responsibility' },
                { xpath: '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p',         propName: 'industry' },
                // ...
            ];

            var results = {};

            for (var { xpath, propName } of elementsToFind) {
                
                var [el] = await page.$x(xpath);
                results[propName] = !el ? 'Not Found' : await (await el.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();     
            }    

            name.push(results['job_name']);
            country.push(results['country']);
            company.push(results['company']);
            type.push(results['job_type']);
            salary.push(results['salary']);
            skills.push(results['skills']);
            desc.push(results['job_description']);
            req.push(results['job_requirement']);
            resp.push(results['job_responsibility']);
            industry.push(results['industry']);

            //await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#suj-single-jobdetail-wrapper > div.detail-body > div.row > div.col.s12.tabs-wrapper.suj-company-review-tabs-wrapper > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").click())            
        }
        await page.close();
    }

    await browser.close();

    var k=1;
    name.forEach(function(a, index) {
       console.log(k, a);
       k++;
    });
}

start()
```

This is the error that I got
[image]

Is there any way I can crawl the rest of the page by removing the timeout or repeat the code process?

Comment: Did you `page.setDefaultTimeout(0);` as well?

Comment: I've tried it and the code just run for so long @ggorlen

Comment: You probably have an XPath that doesn't exist. I'm [not a huge fan](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors) of the browser-generated XPaths.

Comment: I think so too, because I'm doing a loop that clicks on a link. Every page has 30 of those link but on the last page it's random. How do I make a loop that ends when the link is not exist or unavailable? @ggorlen

Comment: Set a timeout on a `waitFor...`, then catch the error when it throws and break out of the loop. Or use `page.$x` and break out of the loop if the item isn't available.